# Change position of the spinner in cordova-plugin-splashscreen - Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to change the position of the spinner from center center to **bottom center** in the splash screen.

For android, I tried changing the value of `Gravity` and `RelativeLayout` in [SplashScreen.java](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/blob/master/src/android/SplashScreen.java).

Following code brings the spinner to **left bottom**:

```
 centeredLayout.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM); 
.
.
 layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

Help to align it in the bottom center of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

just add Gravit.CENTER and it will work,
centeredLayout.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER);